# iOS Swift - Get the Current Local Time and Date Timestamp

Tags: ios, swift, date, firebase, timestamp

I'm trying to make an attendance app and I am really confused about date and time in iOS and Firebase.

I use date as Key, this is the structure of my Firebase database.

```
--Employees
  --Unique_ID
     --Details
          Name: John
     --Attendance
          --dateToday
              Timein: 8:00 AM
              Timeout: 5:00 PM
              BreakStart: 12:00 PM
              BreakFinish: 1:00 PM
```

This is my code to get the date timestamp I used as Key

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     let now = NSDate()
     let nowTimeStamp = self.getCurrentTimeStampWOMiliseconds(dateToConvert: now)

     // I save this dateToday as Key in Firebase
     dateToday = nowTimeStamp
}


func getCurrentTimeStampWOMiliseconds(dateToConvert: NSDate) -> String {
    let objDateformat: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    objDateformat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let strTime: String = objDateformat.string(from: dateToConvert as Date)
    let objUTCDate: NSDate = objDateformat.date(from: strTime)! as NSDate
    let milliseconds: Int64 = Int64(objUTCDate.timeIntervalSince1970)
    let strTimeStamp: String = "\(milliseconds)"
    return strTimeStamp
}
```

But when I convert it back to date I get 2017-09-22 16:00:00 +0000, which is wrong because it is 23rd of September in my location.

What is the right code to use so that I can get the correct date timestamp and time timestamp?

Comment: It is correct if your time zone is UTC+0800. `print` displays `Date`s always in UTC. And `2017-09-22 16:00:00 +0000` and `2017-09-23 00:00:00 +0800` is exactly the same point in time. By the way: Don't use `NSDate` in Swift 3 at all.

Comment: DateFormatter is heavy object to create so if you call the function often, export it outside the scope of the function

Answer (score 149, accepted):

For saving Current time to firebase database I use Unic Epoch Conversation:

```
let timestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
```

and For Decoding Unix Epoch time to Date().

```
let myTimeInterval = TimeInterval(timestamp)
let time = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(myTimeInterval))
```

Comment: will NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 be calculating the timezone, or is there any way to do this for different timezones?

Comment: Epoch time, by definition, is in UTC. It's the number of seconds/milliseconds elapsed since midnight on January 1, 1970, in the UTC timezone. Time zone information would only be useful for displaying it in a specific human language, not for storing or calculating anything.

Answer (score 68):

If you just want the unix timestamp, create an extension:

```
extension Date {
    func currentTimeMillis() -> Int64 {
        return Int64(self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    }
}
```

Then you can use it just like in other programming languages:

```
let timestamp = Date().currentTimeMillis()
```

Comment: By far the best answer.

Answer (score 25):

First I would recommend you to store your timestamp as a `NSNumber` in your Firebase Database, instead of storing it as a `String`.

Another thing worth mentioning here, is that if you want to manipulate dates with Swift, you'd better use `Date` instead of `NSDate`, except if you're interacting with some Obj-C code in your app.

You can of course use both, but the Documentation states:

> Date bridges to the NSDate class. You can use these interchangeably in
>   code that interacts with Objective-C APIs.

Now to answer your question, I think the problem here is because of the timezone.

For example if you `print(Date())`, as for now, you would get:

```
2017-09-23 06:59:34 +0000
```

This is the Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).

So depending on where you are located (or where your users are located) you need to adjust the timezone before (or after, when you try to access the data for example) storing your `Date`:

```
    let now = Date()

    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current

    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

    let dateString = formatter.string(from: now)
```

Then you have your properly formatted `String`, reflecting the current time at your location, and you're free to do whatever you want with it :) (convert it to a `Date` / `NSNumber`, or store it directly as a `String` in the database..)

Comment: The dateString ends up being correct. However, if I add `formatter.date(from: dateString)` at the end, I get the greenwich mean time again.

Answer (score 20):

in **Swift 5**

```
extension Date {
    static var currentTimeStamp: Int64{
        return Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    }
}
```

call like this:

```
let timeStamp = Date.currentTimeStamp
print(timeStamp)
```

Thanks @lenooh

Answer (score 11):

The simple way to create Current TimeStamp. like below,

```
func generateCurrentTimeStamp () -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss"
    return (formatter.string(from: Date()) as NSString) as String
}

you can call like this:

let timeStmp = generateCurrentTimeStamp()
print("time stamp: \(timeStmp)")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you code for iOS 13.0 or later and want a timestamp, then you can use:

```
let currentDate = NSDate.now
```

Comment: this is not 10-digit timestamp

Answer (score 2):

On expanding @MacacoAzul's answer here is my current working example :

```
import SwiftUI

struct TimestampDemo: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(getActualTimeStamp(1))
            .padding(10)
       
        Text(getActualTimeStamp(2))
            .padding(10)
        
        Text(getActualTimeStamp(3))
            .padding(10)
        
        Text(getActualTimeStamp(4))
            .padding(10)
    }
    
    
    func getActualTimeStamp(_ tipo:Int) -> String {
            let date = Date()
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            if tipo == 1{
                formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
            } else if tipo == 2{
                formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
            }else if tipo == 3{
                formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            }
            else if tipo == 4  {
                formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
            }

            return formatter.string(from: date)
        }
}

struct TimestampDemo_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TimestampDemo()
    }
}
```

[image]

**Swift Language Version :** 5

Answer (score 1):

When we convert a UTC timestamp (`2017-11-06 20:15:33 -08:00`) into a `Date` object, the time zone is zeroed out to GMT. For calculating time intervals, this isn't an issue, but it can be for rendering times in the UI.

I favor the RFC3339 format (`2017-11-06T20:15:33-08:00`) for its universality. The date format in Swift is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXXXX` but RFC3339 allows us to take advantage of the `ISO8601DateFormatter`:

```
func getDateFromUTC(RFC3339: String) -> Date? {
    let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    return formatter.date(from: RFC3339)
}
```

RFC3339 also makes time-zone extraction simple:

```
func getTimeZoneFromUTC(RFC3339: String) -> TimeZone? {

    switch RFC3339.suffix(6) {

    case "+05:30":
        return TimeZone(identifier: "Asia/Kolkata")

    case "+05:45":
        return TimeZone(identifier: "Asia/Kathmandu")

    default:
        return nil

    }

}
```

There are 37 or so other time zones we'd have to account for and it's up to you to determine which ones, because there is no definitive list. Some standards count fewer time zones, some more. Most time zones break on the hour, some on the half hour, some on `0:45`, some on `0:15`.

We can combine the two methods above into something like this:

```
func getFormattedDateFromUTC(RFC3339: String) -> String? {

    guard let date = getDateFromUTC(RFC3339: RFC3339),
        let timeZone = getTimeZoneFromUTC(RFC3339: RFC3339) else {
            return nil
    }

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "h:mma EEE, MMM d yyyy"
    formatter.amSymbol = "AM"
    formatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
    formatter.timeZone = timeZone // preserve local time zone
    return formatter.string(from: date)

}
```

And so the string `"2018-11-06T17:00:00+05:45"`, which represents 5:00PM somewhere in Kathmandu, will print `5:00PM Tue, Nov 6 2018`, displaying the local time, regardless of where the machine is.

As an aside, I recommend storing dates as strings remotely (including Firestore which has a native date object) because, I think, remote data should agnostic to create as little friction between servers and clients as possible.

Answer (score 1):

you can even create a function to return different time stamps depending on your necessity:

```
func dataatual(_ tipo:Int) -> String {
        let date = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        if tipo == 1{
            formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        } else if tipo == 2{
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
        } else {
            formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        }

        return formatter.string(from: date)
    }
```