# What is the best way to deal with Date in iOS / Android and Firebase?

Tags: java, android, ios, firebase, swift3

I'm developing two native apps in android and iOS (swift3) and some of my classes use Date object, but when I save a Date object from android into Firebase Realtime Database the structure is something like this:

`creationDate: {
 date: 3
 day: 2
 hours: 17
 minutes: 27
 month: 9
 seconds: 43
 time: 1507062463000
 timezoneOffset: 180
 year: 117
}`

But this is not a common structure in iOS (by my searches off course).

What is a better solution:

1. Create a encoder/decoder in iOS to read and write this structure?
2. Change read and write in android to save in firebase with iso date? Something like this (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ)

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend the second option you listed so that, in the future, your data is more flexible if you need it for anything else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Swift - Get the Current Local Time and Date Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376823/ios-swift-get-the-current-local-time-and-date-timestamp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using `FIRServerValue.timestamp()`. This will ensure that a Firebase Server timestamp will be used when the data is saved to the database, that is the most accurate time because it can't be tampered by a user, and will be exactly the same across iOS and Android.

The data saved is the number of milliseconds since 1970, which you can easily convert into a date object.

For example (Swift):

```
myRef.setValue(FIRServerValue.timestamp())
```

Edit: Firebase 4

```
myRef.setValue(ServerValue.timestamp())
```

Comment: Ok, thanks by reply!! But do you know if this will work in cases of offline mode?

Comment: Yes it will still work, but will use the user’s device timestamp until the data is sent to the server, where the value will be updated by the much more accurate Firebase timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS Use this

For saving Current time to firebase database I use Unic Epoch Conversation:

```
let timestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
```

and For Decoding Unix Epoch time to Date().

```
let myTimeInterval = TimeInterval(timestamp)
let time = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(myTimeInterval))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a timestamp *(number of seconds since the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970 at UTC)* :

**iOS (Swift)**

```
// Get current timestamp
let currentTimestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

// Get date from timestamp
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(TimeInterval(yourTimestamp)))
```

**android (Kotlin)** (Take care, in android the timestamp is in milliseconds)

```
// Get current timestamp
val currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 // We want timestamp in seconds

// Get date from timestamp
val date = Date(yourTimestamp * 1000) // Timestamp must be in ms to be converted to Date
```