# Current Date to milliseconds with 10 digits in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to convert current date into milliseconds with 10 digits only
for example: 26/09/2019 current date to 1569592800 milliseconds in swift and store it in variable to use it in project
I want to use it in this function:

```
func fetchPopularGames(for platform: Platform, completion: @escaping (Result<[Game], Error>) -> Void) {
    iGDB.apiRequest(endpoint: .GAMES, apicalypseQuery: "fields name, first_release_date, id, popularity, rating, involved_companies.company.name, cover.image_id; where (platforms = (49,130,48,6) & first_release_date > 1569592800); sort first_release_date asc; limit 50;", dataResponse: { bytes in
        guard let gameResults = try? Proto_GameResult(serializedData: bytes) else {
            return
        }
        let games = gameResults.games.map { Game(game: $0) }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          completion(.success(games))
        }
    }, errorResponse: { error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    })
}
```

especially in this part in the query 
 first_release_date > 1569592800

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52728519/6098786 check this, May be helpful for you

Comment: How to limit the digit to 10 it print 13 digits:  1569487396667
I want to convert the date without time for example: 20/09/2019 without any time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

`let timeStamp = Int(1000 * Date().timeIntervalSince1970)`

Convert the current date to time interval (milliseconds since 1970).

You can also use this to check the conversion: https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: `timeIntervalSince1970` returns the timestamp in *seconds,* not milliseconds.

Comment: It is better to use `Int64` (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40135192/1187415). Int is a 32-bit integer on some platforms, which may be too small for a milliseconds timestamp.

Comment: how to format the numbers to be 10 digits only not 13 digits

Comment: The numbers with 10 digits is interval in second, 13-digit numbers will be in millisecond. Let's choose the one that's suitable for your system.

Comment: It has to be milliseconds with 10 digits without the time only the date

Comment: Sounds confused, it should be either 13-digit (in millisecond) or 10-digit (in second)

Comment: It it ok but now I need my current date to be convert it to milliseconds not since 1970

Comment: You need a milestone to convert your current date to millisecond - the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970 at UTC.